# How to create a docker image from dotnet core 2.2 and powershell core?

Tags: docker, .net-core, powershell-core

I'm trying to "dockerize" a dotnet standard library, for now I'm using a simple docker file, to build and pack it using just dotnet cli commands.

```
# Build stage
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build
ARG Version
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build -p:Version=$Version -c Release --no-restore

RUN dotnet pack -p:Version=$Version -c Release --include-symbols --no-restore --no-build -o /src/.artifacts
```

I want to be able to run a powershell script ci.ps1 from my docker file, but there is no powershell core installed in the dotnet:2.2-sdk.

Is there any examples out there on how to run powershell core scripts from inside a dotnet image ? How can I create my own image from powershell core and dotnet sdk ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install it. Like `RUN apt install powershell`

Comment: Tried apt-get update && apt-get install -y powershell, but I have an error : Unable to locate package powershell

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6#ubuntu-1604) to ms documentation can help. They recommand to install the Microsoft repository GPG keys first

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case I recently needed to implement, and you can indeed get Powershell Core up and running from a .NET Core SDK image - in my case the below was done against image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch`.

The full solution looks something like as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
...

FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN dotnet tool install --global PowerShell \
&& ln -s /root/.dotnet/tools/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh
```

Where:

- `dotnet tool install --global PowerShell` installs PowerShell into the container. However this alone is not quite good enough because as observed in @amirtharaj-rs answer, the command pwsh will not work unless invoked from the PowerShell installation directory.
  For example, you may encounter something like:

```
root@a1d30119664d:/app# pwsh 
bash: pwsh: command not found
```

- `ln -s /root/.dotnet/tools/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh` creates a link called `pwsh` which points to where PowerShell is installed. This is the key line which enables `pwsh` to be invoked from anywhere:

```
root@a1d30119664d:/app# pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.
```

If the above does not work, then you may need to ensure that the execute bit is set on `/usr/bin/pwsh`. You can check this by running `ls -l /usr/bin/pwsh`.

If you do need to set the execute bit, add `chmod 755 /root/.dotnet/tools/pwsh` to the Dockerfile `RUN` command. So the complete `RUN` command would look something like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
...

FROM build AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN dotnet tool install --global PowerShell \
&& ln -s /root/.dotnet/tools/pwsh /usr/bin/pwsh
&& chmod 755 /root/.dotnet/tools/pwsh
```

If interested, I learnt the above via the discussion history on this Github issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1862.

Answer (score 0):

dotnet global tool provide powershell support which can be used as pwsh.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
USER ContainerAdministrator
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet tool install --global PowerShell
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\ContainerUser\.dotnet\tools"
COPY ["publish/"," ."]
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Users\\ContainerAdministrator\\.dotnet\\tools\\pwsh.exe", "C:\\app\\PowershellScript.ps1"]
```

even after setting path i am not able use pwsh (powershell ) directly but after going inside installed path ..it provide powershell functionality